# Online SQL Server database accessed from my software

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have been working on the software using a SQL Server database. Now I am in the phase when I would like to provide this software for other people, but I don't know how to manage the database. The thing is that it is really inconvenient when installing my software to also install SQL Server at the users computer (many unexpected thing could happen).

Therefore I thought that I would pay for web hosting with SQL Server, but it is:

1. **Expensive** (just for database with few tables).
2. Most of the web hosting don't offer remote access to the SQL Server database (so I can't connect there from my software).

So there is my question, *what would you do?* My own virtual server? (even more expensive), or would you install SQL Server on users computer? Or do you know where to get only SQL Server hosting for low costs?

Comment: If your software is a standalone app, perhaps consider replacing MS SQL with  embedded database, that you could distribute with your application. There is a few of them - e.g. Derby (http://db.apache.org/derby/) for Java apps or SQLite (http://www.sqlite.org/), that is C-based (there are others as well). Of course, it might or might not be a suitable solution for you, depending on your database requiremets, licensing, needed refactoring of your code etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't advice using a remote SQL Server. SQL Connections strongly depend on network connection and the Internet is not "stable" enough for that. There are also performance issues  that will make your application completely useless.

One important thing you didn't mention is whether different users will share the same data or will have their own. If each user will use their own data you can install a "local" SQL Server  Edition (SQL Compact Edition, here is the reference)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983341(v=vs.110).aspx

In case several users will share the same data, you shouldn't rely on the database solely. One possible approach is having an Application server that implements business logic whereas your desktop application stays actiong as a "dumb" client. This is a lot better for performance and reduce data transfer problems. You can implement webservices for you application server. This is a good solution as the data is transfered from he application server to the clients through HTTP/HTTPS and this relieves you from dealing with ports and other communication issues. An alternative is using Microsoft Communication Framework (WCF)

Good luck!